# How to make an Iron farm in Minecraft survival?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

How can I make an Iron farm using villagers? It would also help if you told me the supplies I need because I would like to implement this into my minecraft survival farm and can you tell me the science behind what is spawning the Iron golems

Comment: Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np7NEx2KdYU)? If so I can summarize it in an answer.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Yep! Just that one works very slow, if there is faster model that is just as easy on rescources to make that would help.

Comment: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BhlLIIpRh4)'s another one, I haven't tried it though

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of iron farms using villagers, one is a bit more harder to make but will work in Minecraft peaceful. The first one is to get villager(s) into a space and put a zombie or hostile mob beside it, and limit the spawning range. The villagers gets scared so the game spawns an iron golem, if you limit the spawning range, it will spawn where your want to, and you kill it to get iron (or automate it). The other is to get 5 villagers or more to make the game think there's a village there so it spawns an iron golem, same concept as for the killing. If you want any both of these farms, here are some recommendations:

Normal (Zombie) -

Peaceful (5 Villagers) -

These may or may not work depending on the verison your playing on.

If they don't work you can tell me the verison you're on and I will find you some that works.

Sorry for the late response -xBRUHHY

Comment: Hi xBruhhy, if you post links to videos, please at least summarize their content. It's also good to disclose your affiliation. Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: There are many mechanics that effect iron golem spawning. I would suggest looking at the minecraft.fandom.com pages tutorials/iron golem farming, iron_golem#spawning, and villager#iron_golem_summoning for more info.